# Application works on emulator, but not on real device - float type

Tags: android

My application works great while using the emulator, but it crashes while working on real device. I code it for Android 2.2. Real device is 2.3.6.

**Problem is here:**

When I use something like that:

```
tvPlayerOneScores.setText("-" + numberFormat.format(level));
```

it works great both on emulator and real device.

But when I try this:

```
tvPlayerOneScores.setText("-" + numberFormat.format(level * 0.5f));
```

it works on emulator, but crashes on real device.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:362)
    at com.amrotek.truthordare.GameActivity$4.onClick(GameActivity.java:287)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:
I multiplied all values by 10, so I only work with integer numbers when I do arithmetic operations. At the end I just divide end value by 10. It works :)

Comment: What exception do you get? Post a stack trace of the crash

Comment: Yep, will need a stack trace like raghav has mentioned

Comment: Which line is GameActivity.java:287?

Comment: @m0skit0 Line 287:

`playerOnePoints = Float.valueOf(numberFormat.format(playerOnePoints - level * 0.5f));`

Comment: Well with this information we unfortunately cannot help you. That really tells us nothing about the values. Did you debug it?

Comment: @m0skit0 
About the values:
float playerOnePoints = 0;
byte level = 1; // possible values {1;2;3;4;5}
What do you mean with debugging in this case? How Can I debug it?

Comment: I mean the values when the exception happens, not the initialization values. Sorry but this is not the place to show you how to debug, this is something you're supposed to know how to do if you're a developer. [Here's a video anyway](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A)

Answer (score 1):

you should have included faulty line in the question not in the comments:

```
playerOnePoints = Float.valueOf(numberFormat.format(playerOnePoints - level * 0.5f));
```

since it's not enough to make a conclusion, here's a short list of things for you to check:

1. why do you need to format a number with `numberFormat` just to convert it back with `valueOf`?
2. what's the `numberFormat`, does it really produce *valid* float strings?
3. is `playerOnePoints` float or Float? should not you use `parseFloat()` instead of `valueOf()`?

Finally, if you still are unable to solve your problem, I'd suggest to replace the aforementioned line with simple:

```
playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints - level * 0.5f;
```

That should do the trick =)

ps. also you migth want to get acquainted with `Math.floor()/ceil()`, if I understood your intentions with `parseFloat()/numberFormat()` correctly.